# What happens when I print(*args) (notice the star *)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing a function to find the number of unique words from input.

At a moment when i was bored and try to do nothing to kill time, I wished to print all words that was passed to the function via ***arg**.

It is known that ***args** was a tuple, so the code

```
print(arg)
```

was supposed to out put "('babe', 'I', 'love', 'you')" or "('babe', 'I', 'love', 'you', 'do', 'you', 'love', 'me')", and I knew that.

However, there is a typo in my code, a unexpected "*". So the code is actually:

```
print(*arg)
```

why it work, why didn't it raise an exception? None of Google , Baidu nor Bing had the answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `*a` instead of `a` in general throws an error, because they are different. `*a` in a function call `foo(*a)` would be equivalent to `foo(a[0], a[1], ...)`, i.e., pass each element of `a` as a separate argument. This is called "unpacking." On the other hand, `foo(a)` would pass the whole iterable `a` as a single argument to `foo`.

But why didn't your case throw an error? It's because `print` also accepts multiple arguments, and then print each argument delimited by a blank (by default):

```py
a = ('hello', 'world')

print(a) # ('hello', 'world')
print(*a) # hello world
print('hello', 'world') # hello world
```

In this example the second and the third lines of `print` are the same; `print(*a)` is equivalent to `print(a[0], a[1])` which is `print('hello', 'world')`.

In contrast, the first one is different. In that case, you are giving a tuple to `print`, so that it prints the *string representation*, `"('hello', 'world')"` of that tuple.

Comment: And implicit in the previous answer.  `*x` is allowed as an argument to a python function.  It just means that x is sequence-like, and that the values of that sequence should be inserted as arguments.  `foo('a', *range(5), 'b')` is the same as `foo('a', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'b')`.

Comment: @FrankYellin Yes, and actually unpacking has been generalized further; for example, you can now do something like `x = [2, 3, 4]; lst = [1, *x]`. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/.